# Replacement for DOM3 getUserData/setUserData methods

Tags: jquery, dom, cross-browser, deprecated, dom3

So we've got some old-school Firefox extension code that uses the [DOM3 methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-getUserData) `get/setUserData()` to pass around data in the DOM.  Unfortunately, these have been [deprecated in DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-core), so Firefox is [planning to drop support for them](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749981), and Chrome never supported them in the first place.

Is there a cross-browser replacement?  jQuery's `$.data` seems to be an option, but 'pure' JavaScript would be preferable.

Comment: Can't you just "steal" the implementation of `$.data`?

Comment: We considered that, but it's surprisingly complex and tied to a lot of other jQuery functions: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=data

Comment: Still a good question, jquery is the obvious solution but surely there has to be a non jquery solution as the original question asks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end we decided to go with jQuery after all, the core library is only around 75k and it solves the problem very cleanly:

```
element.getUserData('foo') --> $(element).data('foo')

element.setUserData('foo', 'bar', null) --> $(element).data('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: "Only 75k"? That sounds like a lot to me.

Comment: It might be time to upgrade your Commodore 64? ;).  It's an extension, not a web page, the 75k is only downloaded once on install.

Comment: Only downloaded once, but it has to be *executed* for every page load, right? Or does it just run in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom event which can store data in the `detail`

Ref: [How can I transfer data to firefox extension from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972071/how-can-i-transfer-data-to-firefox-extension-from-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Just set any property you want on the element.

```
element.key = value;
```

DOM elements/nodes are **just JavaScript objects**. To avoid name clashes with native properties (like `id`, etc.), you could prefix your keys with an underscore.

```
element._id = "foo";
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Extensions are pretty severely sandboxed.

Comment: @jpatokal I haven't tried it, but this shouldn't cause any problems. If your jQuery solution works, then so will this, because both of them store properties direct on DOM objects. See the source: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=_internalData