# Replacement of Element.setUserData

Tags: javascript

Before element.setUserData is deprecated in Firefox, I use it to store and attach some data to one element. But now from the doc: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.setUserData

We can see that this API is deprecated and Element.dataset is preferred.
I use element.setUserData to store object or array, but element.dataset can only store string.

So is there any other replacement for store object and attach it to an element?

Comment: Check [Replacement for DOM3 getUserData/setUserData methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943519/replacement-for-dom3-getuserdata-setuserdata-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [How can I transfer data to firefox extension from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972071/how-can-i-transfer-data-to-firefox-extension-from-web-page)

Use a CustomEvent, which can carry custom data in the .detail member.
From web:

```
  var event = new CustomEvent("custom-event-id", {
  "bubbles": true,
  "detail": {
    "some": "data",
    "number": 1
  }
});
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

From extension:

```
someWindowOrElement.addEventListener("custom-event-id", function(e) {
  console.log("got event for ", e.originalTarget, "with data", e.detail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.. serialize your array into a string then take that sting and convert it back into an array....

var aUserData = new Array( "This", "Is", "Easy" ) ;

var sUserData = aUserData.toString( "|" ) ;  //  Serialize Array

var aBackFromString = sUserData.split( "|" ) ;  //  Convert String Back To Array

Comment: Yes, I have come up with this idea. But if the object is too large, I think this maybe is not the best choice.

Comment: Is there some API just behave the same as Element.setUserData?

Comment: The size of the data matters not whether it is an array or a string.